# Interpreting iOS crash reports

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm experiencing multiple crashes where it appears that a native iOS method is calling functions from a third-party library.  Here's an example:

```
Thread: Unknown Name (Crashed)
0     libsystem_kernel.dylib                0x33222350 __pthread_kill + 8 + 8
1     libsystem_c.dylib                     0x3500f973 abort + 95 + 94
2     libsystem_c.dylib                     0x34ff04d1 basename + 1
3     FireChat                              0x00036489 -[OTOverlayButton drawRect:] + 1
4     Foundation                            0x37a4a5a9 -[NSDictionary(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 33 + 32
5     FireChat                              0x709d -[NetworkModel getUserForUid:] (NetworkModel.m:150)
6     FireChat                              0x0001c42f -[OpenTokController session:didReceiveStream:] (OpenTokController.m:258)
7     libdispatch.dylib                     0x32da011f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 11 + 10
8     libdispatch.dylib                     0x32d9f4b7 _dispatch_client_callout + 23 + 22
9     libdispatch.dylib                     0x32da41bd _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 225 + 224
10   CoreFoundation                         0x37dbbf3b __CFRunLoopRun + 1291 + 1290
11   CoreFoundation                         0x37d2eebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357 + 356
12   CoreFoundation                         0x37d2ed49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105 + 104
13   GraphicsServices                       0x358e22eb GSEventRunModal + 75 + 74
14   UIKit                                  0x3a1b42f9 UIApplicationMain + 1121 + 1120
15   FireChat                               0x43b3 main (main.m:8)
```

To me, it appears that the `[NSDictionary valueForKey:]` method is invoking `[OTOverlayButton drawRect:]` which comes from a third-party library.  This shouldn't be possible -- am I reading the crash report wrong?

`[OTOverlayButton drawRect:]` isn't called anywhere in my code.  Note that the dictionary contains (my) objects which contain pointers to objects from the third-party library.

The library vendor and I are both baffled.

Thanks.

Comment: it seems, drawRect: is called from NSDictionary. Get sure, key param in NetworkModel getUserForUid: is valid

Comment: In a Release build, sometimes there might be bogus stack frames? The `drawRect` call may be just a red herring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the cause of this crash was memory corruption resulting from calling `performSelector:` on a method that returned a struct.  See this blog post for more details:

[Why performSelector is more dangerous than I thought](http://tomdalling.com/blog/cocoa/why-performselector-is-more-dangerous-than-i-thought/)